# Output *.js files to *.ts files to output directory on build

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, msbuild, typescript

I have a console application (.exe) that utilizes compiled TypeScript. The only problem is that the *.js files are not copied to the output directory using the default MSBuild and TypeScript build targets.

What is the cleanest way to copy all the generated JavaScript files to the output directory to their respective folders without adding them to the *.csproj? I do not want to redirect all output files to the same directory as could be done with tsconfig.

Also note that adding this afterbuild target:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="**\*.js" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

does not work when using MSBuild.